# Does Microsoft Edge support aria live regions?

Tags: accessibility, microsoft-edge, wai-aria

Does Microsoft Edge support aria live regions?

I tried testing it @ http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/live3.shtml

It works fine with IE using Jaws, narrator and NVDA. But not with Edge.

If edge doesn't support aria-live, Is there any alternative to get similar behavior.

I am working on a chat application. Ans I need screen readers to read incoming messages in chat. Is there anyway to achieve it without aria-live?

Thanks
Dasari

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft Edge supports ARIA live regions.

Edge does not support JAWS nor NVDA (or vice-versa, depending who you ask), so live regions will not work with either of those screen readers.

Narrator works with Edge. It is not perfect, but it is coming along. Using [your demo page](http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/live3.shtml) with Edge and Narrator, the live region worked as expected. I am using the Windows 10 Creators Update with Edge 40.15063.0.0.

From [Screen readers and web browsers – what’s the best pairing for testing?](http://hollier.info/browserpairing/) at the end of March 2017:

> At the moment Microsoft still recommends Narrator users in Windows 10 use Internet Explorer, but with updates to both Narrator and Edge in the insider preview of Windows 10 likely to be released later in the year.  This will become an option for testing.

There are official statements, and inklings of the direction at the Microsoft User Voice forum, but now I am way beyond the scope of your question now.

Comment: I didn't know that, but you are right. Good info to know. It looks like when Microsoft built the Edge browser, they transitioned from MSAA to a new accessibility API called UI Automation (UIA)... and JAWS does not currently support UIA. Both Freedom Scientific and Microsoft suggest JAWS users continue using IE 11 instead. With that said, FS is working on Edge support and will be supporting it soon.

Comment: Thanks aardrian.Its working with narrator. Also thanks a lot for sharing the article.

Comment: This is great information that backs up my testing. Too bad the main page for JAWS screen reader says this:
"Works with the latest versions of Microsoft Office, Google Docs, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Edge, and much more"
This is false advertising and wastes people's time as they fumble with JAWS + Edge, as I did.

Comment: @flyer my answer is over a year old. JAWS is on 2019 now and generally works better with Edge (or vice versa). Since then JAWS has made an open issue tracker if you want to file bugs: https://github.com/FreedomScientific/VFO-standards-support